# Camunda rest engine json number as BigDecimal

Tags: json, bigdecimal, camunda

I've downloaded the camunda bpm platform in order to evaluate dmn decisions by using the rest api.

For that I deploy this decision table:

[image]

And send this json request:

```
{
    "variables":
    {
        "a": {
            "value": 100.01
        },
        "b": {
            "value": 10.01
        }
    }
}
```

I receive the following response:

```
[
    {
        "result": {
            "type": "Double",
            "value": 110.02000000000001,
            "valueInfo": {}
        }
    }
]
```

I expect that the value of "result" were "110.02" but instead it gives "110.02000000000001".
The issue is that camunda "engine-rest" receives numbers as "Double", so by making a sum it looses precision.

It's there a way for making camunda "engine-rest" receives numbers from json as "BigDecimal" instead of "Double" in order to not loose precision?.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://jira.camunda.com/browse/CAM-7123?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel) thread discusses your problem. Looks like it's an open bug.

*"Below, you can find a test class which evaluates a simple decision table with a decimal result type, showcasing it being rounded to the nearest double value if it's not surrounded by quotes."*

Sounds just like what you're looking for.

Best regards
Sebastian

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've already seen that thread before, it's related but it's not the same problem.  
In the mentioned thread an example is shown, this is done by using directly the "camunda-dmn-engine". If I used it directly and send "a" and "b" as BIgDecimal I don't have any issues.  
But as I use the "camunda-bpm-platform", which uses a web layer "engine-rest" to receive json input and convert them into java objects in order to call "camunda-dmn-engine", numbers in json are converted into Double, loosing precision when executing "a + b".